# Integral Equality; Distribution vs. Function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

If the following two equalities hold...

$\int \omega(x) dG(x) = 1$

$\int \omega(x) \Omega(x) dG(x) = 1$

... is it necessarily the case that the functions $\omega(x)$ and $\omega(x)\Omega(x)$ are equal?  ie

$\Rightarrow \omega(x) = \omega(x)\Omega(x) \Rightarrow \Omega(x) = 1$

Comment: No, and there are plenty of counterexamples. $\int fd\mu=\int gd\mu$ does not imply $f=g$.

Comment: Okay, I have made it an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not the case and there are plenty of counterexamples.

It is not legal to conclude: $$f=g$$ purely on base of: $$\int fd\mu=\int gd\mu$$